# My signup page refershes instead of submitting to database

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

After submit btn is clicked it is supposed to redirect to homepage. Please I need help
This was working fine in xampp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please consider adding more helpful details about your problem. Post the code you tried to write or explain your problem in more details. Also, read question guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you post your codes. Can you post the code you were redirecting to. We need to see your little work before providing feedback.